# "Always Move Messages in this Conversation" missing on Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm on outlook 2010, and I have the Always Move Messages in this Conversation option missing in the move menu. Can somebody help me please as to why this is happening?

Also, is it possible to make a "quick step" to always move messages in a conversation to a certain folder?

I'm using Windows 7 and I believe that the indexing service is off (not very sure though, I can check if needed, just don't know how to do that)

**EDIT**
I also see that the "Ignore" button in the delete area on the ribbon is disabled for me

**EDIT** To clarify, I was talking about the context menu when I right click an email, and the "move.." option that comes with it is missing. Here is a screen shot of one that works to clarify the point, I've highlighted where the option should be

[image]

Comment: You have a move menu? Or are you suggesting you had a Move To Folder option within QuickSteps which has disappeared?

Comment: Edited question for clarification, i was talking about the move option in the right click context menu.

Comment: I've made an edit to your post, can you confirm if the picture I've input is what you are referring too and if the picture is indeed accurate (if not, please take a screenshot yourself or use the snipping tool)

Comment: On one of my computers, I can't see always move messages in this conversation.

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook, find the Quick Steps pane of the Home ribbon. This has a scroll option, it's possible that you've added a new Quick Step and it's moved your Move to Folder to the bottom of the list?

Expand Quick Steps.

Click New, the option for `Move to Folder` is here.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my question for clarification. I was talking about the move option in right click context menu.